# ConnectionString object instantiation

Tags: asp.net, .net

Where and when should i store and instantiate a ConnectionString (got from web.config) object to be used in an ASP.NET WebApp UI layer, to be passed be passed through Business Layer and Data Access Layer (all layers are different projects/dll).

I know out to create it, and access, i'm just wondering which is the best practice, a Global.asax Property ConnectionString ? Instantiated when (Application_Start, Session_Start)? A Session item?

Thanks for reading, please shout your opinion!

Comment: Why does the UI need a connection string?  Wouldn't that be used exclusively by the Data Access Layer?

Comment: Yes, but for scalability reasons i think the connection string should be in the UI, lets say we change our DAL

Comment: How are those "scalability" reasons?

Comment: lets say we change our DAL?

Comment: Suppose you do.  You're still assuming that your data store needs a single piece of connection information, and that it's a string.  You will have built a lot of code, multiple layers of it, around this assumption.  Then suppose some of your data has to move - to another database, or to the cloud. You now have two types of connections you need to make.  What then? How have you saved yourself trouble by building 3 layers around this single assumption?

Comment: The tl;dr; of it:  you're better off NOT building more dependencies than you can help between layers, because then changes to one layer affect every other layer. And it's the changes you didn't anticipate ever having to make that get you.

Comment: humm i see your point, but doesn't the connectionstring needs to be in the web.config, there for, the UI?

Comment: If you mean, "Can other assemblies besides the Web UI access things in the web.config?" the answer is "yes".  See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987208/using-web-config-as-store-for-referenced-class-librarys-properties-settings-cla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your DAL read your connectionstring from your UI web.config. Your presentation layer and business layer do not need to know your database connection string and should not be passed through between layers. So you can initialize it in DAL or put it in constructor. remember to open and close your connection for every method you call in DAL.